# Table with jQuery appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create **table** with these span and a href's. There must be just one tr and 3 td.

```
updater: function (selectedCustomer) {
      valueAccessor()( parseInt(selectedCustomer.split('-')[0]));
        if (valueAccessor()() > 0) {
           $(element).hide();
        var txt = $('<span>' + selectedCustomer + '</span>').appendTo($(element).parent());
        var openCust = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" type="submit"style=" margin-top: 7pt;"><i class="icon-search" style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000;"></i></a>').appendTo($(element).parent());
        var btn = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" type="submit"style=" margin-top: 7pt;"><i class="icon-remove" style="font-size: 14pt; color: #000000;"></i></a>').appendTo($(element).parent());
        btn.on("click", function () {
            $(element).show();
            txt.remove();
            btn.remove();
            openCust.remove();
            valueAccessor()(0);
          })
          openCust.on("click", function () {
             OpenCustomer(valueAccessor()());
          })
       }
      //  OpenCustomer(selectedCustomer);
     }
 });
```

I want to see my html like;

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><span>abc554444</span></td>
      <td><a href>dsadasda</a> </td>
      <td><a href>dsadasda</a> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How can I add **table, tr, td** tags to my code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it as simple example so that you can see how I first instantiate new elements, then manipulate, text, link etc.. and finaly I append it with jQuery ..

```
var ah = $('<a/>')
var sp = $('<span/>')
var td = $('<td/>')
var tr = $('<tr/>')
    tr.append( td.clone().append( ah ).attr('href', '#').text('Link text') )
    tr.append( td.clone().append( sp ).text('Lorem Ipsum') )
    tr.append( td.clone().append( sp ).text('New Lorem Ipsum') )
var tb = $('<table/>').append(tr)
// append to body or some other element :)
$('body').append( tb )
```

http://codepen.io/mkdizajn/pen/BQgEWQ?editors=0110

hth, k

Answer (score 0):

How I like to do it: create the different components ie span, a with hrefs etc. then append to

```
<table id="theTable">
    <tr></tr>
</table>


var mySpan = "<span>What i want in it</span>";
var firstLink = "<a href='"+what ever i want here+"'>The other bits in here</a>";
var secondLink = "<a href='foo'>All the other stuff</a>";

$("body").on("click", ".myButton", function(){
    $("#myTable tr").empty();
    $("#theTable tr").append("<td>"+mySPan+"</td><td>"+firstLink+"</td><td>"+secondLink+"</td>");
});
```

The simple way usually works.